# PHP TNTClassifier likelihood probability distribution

Tags: php, classification, probability

I'm using the TNT Search Text Classification module,
https://github.com/teamtnt/tntsearch, and it works good, the problem is I do not know how to interpret the results - more specifically the likelihood of correct match. I have read that it uses [Naive Bayes classifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naive_Bayes_classifier) but I'm unable to find what kind of probability distribution is the result. I've got my own small testing dataset of about 50 values (50 / 10 = 5 categories) and the guesses are fairly correct.

However, the likelihood number that this tool provides is a negative number somewhere in the range of about -15 to -25.

The question is, what value could be interpreted as not credible? Let's say that the tool is only <33% sure. What value would correspond to this assumption?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got in touch with the TNTSearch developers. The classifier doesn't actually return a probability but a "highest score". And only for the best match.

As advised, I have made some changes to the code.

In class `TeamTNT\TNTSearch\Classifier\TNTClassifier` I changed bits in the `predict` method (softmax function inspired from [here](https://gist.github.com/raymondjplante/d826df05349c1d4350e0aa2d7ca01da4)):

```
public function predict($statement)
{
    $words = $this->tokenizer->tokenize($statement);

    $best_likelihoods = [];
    $best_likelihood = -INF;
    $best_type       = '';
    foreach ($this->types as $type) {
        $best_likelihoods[$type] = -INF;
        $likelihood = log($this->pTotal($type)); // calculate P(Type)
        $p          = 0;
        foreach ($words as $word) {
            $word = $this->stemmer->stem($word);
            $p += log($this->p($word, $type));
        }
        $likelihood += $p; // calculate P(word, Type)
        if ($likelihood > $best_likelihood) {
            $best_likelihood = $likelihood;
            $best_likelihoods[$type] = $likelihood;
            $best_type       = $type;
        }
    }

    return [
        'likelihood' => $best_likelihood,
        'likelihoods' => $best_likelihoods,
        'probability' => $this->softmax($best_likelihoods),
        'label'      => $best_type
    ];
}
```

**The percentual probability can be then found in `$guess['probability']['$label']`.**